# bpy scripting: Join objects in a collection

Tags: python, scripting, collections

How can I join all objects in a collection? This is what i have so far:

```
def final():
    Coll=bpy.data.collections['low']
    #finalColl=bpy.data.collections['final']
    for obj in Coll.objects:
        if obj.type=='MESH':
           ob.join
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure you have selected all the objects you want to join using `obj.select_set(True)` in the *for* loop and make sure one of the objects is *active* (yellow outline). Then you can join them using `bpy.ops.object.join()` after the loop has finished.

```
import bpy

def final():
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

        Coll = bpy.data.collections['low']
        for obj in Coll.objects:
            if obj.type == 'MESH':
               obj.select_set(True)
        #bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
        bpy.ops.object.join()

final()
```

Comment: Thank you! I've hear bpy.ops isn't the mos performant way to do things. is there a method that just uses python?

Comment: nope. in this case bpy.ops is the way to go.